# Turtles spaced per patch

Tags: netlogo, agent

```
  to create-wall
  set breadth-patches patches with[(pycor > (-(breadth)) and pycor < breadth and pxcor = lengthrec) or(pycor > (-(breadth)) and pycor < breadth and pxcor = (-(lengthrec))) ]
  set length-patches patches with[(pxcor > (-(lengthrec)) and pxcor < lengthrec and pycor = (-(breadth - 1))) or (pxcor > (-(lengthrec)) and pxcor < lengthrec and pycor = (breadth - 1))]
  set gap-patches patches with [pxcor > (gap * (-1)) and pxcor < gap and pycor =(breadth - 1)]
  set length-patches length-patches with [not member? self gap-patches]
  ask breadth-patches[

    sprout-walls 1[set color 2
      set size 0.5 set heading 180 fd 0.25
      if-else(pxcor < 0)[set heading 90][set heading 270] fd 0.25]
    sprout-walls 1[set color 2
      set size 0.5 set heading 360 fd 0.25
     if-else(pxcor < 0)[set heading 90][set heading 270] fd 0.25]

    ]
  ask length-patches[
   sprout-walls 1[
         set color 2
         set size 0.5 set heading 90  fd 0.25
         if-else(pycor < 0)
           [
              set heading 180] 
           [ 
                set heading 0] 
         fd 0.25
         ]
   sprout-walls 1[
          set color 2
          set size 0.5 
          set heading 270 
          fd 0.25
          if-else(pycor < 0)
            [
                set heading 180]
            [
              set heading 0] fd 0.25
     ]
   ]  
end
```

The above create a box as below:

[image]

Therefore there are two turtles/walls per patch. I wish increase it to three or if possible write a code with which I can variate the number the turtles/wall per patch as a variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are doing then changing the 1 in sprout-walls one to a variable should do it.
Set a 3

Sprout-walls a [...stuff..]

A could be a input or slider variable as well.

To randomly spread them across the patch.

Put this into to sprout

```
Setxy (xcor + random-float 1 - .5) (ycor + random-float 1 - .5)
```

To line them up would similar I will write it as a procedure

```
to Make-line [number orientation]
  Let c 0 ;; this is a counter
  Crt 5
  [  
  ;; your create code goes here
  Let c c + 1
  Set heading orientation bk .5 fd ( c / ( number + 1)  
  ]
End
```

Number is the number of turtles you want orientation is horizontal at 0 vertical at 90

Comment: that would create turtles on top of each other.

Comment: I see it was unclear. Do you want them to be in a line? Or randomly distributed across the patch?

Comment: I want them to be "in a line".

Comment: Set heading 0 bk .5 fd ( count turtles-here/a ) ;; my fear is that they last turtle is right at the edge so /(a+1) might be better.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your solution. What is the use of random-float.

Comment: That is to distribute them across the patch. Integers are patch centers. You wanted a line so I added the line example I added to my answer.

Comment: I am exactly able to understand your implementation. If possible can you please make changes in the code I have posted, I will give me a better idea.